# Can VirtualBox return IP address for launched VM?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I would like to start my VM from the command line and without the GUI using the following command:

`VBoxManage startvm <MY_VM> --type headless`

and the SSH into it from the next prompt.  The problem, however, is that my laptop is on office WiFi, which uses DHCP, so the IP address assigned to the VM instance changes almost every time.  When I launch the GUI, I can fetch the IP and then close it and SSH into it, however, I find this step rather annoying and seemingly needless (or should be).

Is there any way to have the `VBoxManage` utility return the IP address for the newly launched instance, which I would then use to SSH into it?

I shall add that I have used `Vagrant` to launch `VirtualBox` which circumvents the need for IP (just do `vagrant ssh`) but Vagrant has some other oddities I would like to avoid, i.e. use bare `VirtualBox`.

Comment: You can't access the machine by DNS (hostname) or Samba (NetBIOS)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if the ip is assigned by virtualbox, you can get it.

```
VBoxManage guestproperty get yourvmname "/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/V4/IP"
```

Comment: I ran that and got `No value set!`

Comment: that would indicate that virtualbox either failed to allocate the ip, or the ip is otherwise set by something else (such as a bridged network so it is set by a dhcp server outside virtualbox).

Comment: i set the network config to bridged and also installed guest additions and now this works.  thanks

Comment: Thx @amphibient your comment saved my day - had to reboot / renew my ip config but then it finally worked.