# How do I setup an IP address on my virtualbox VM?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a VM which I run on VirtualBox like so ...

```
    $ VBoxManage startvm --type headless dev-006
```

... and I can see that NIC1 is "Bridged" and setup like so ...

```
    $ VBoxManage showvminfo dev-006 --details
    ...
    NIC 1:           MAC: 080027A7F746, Attachment: Bridged Interface 'eth1', Cable connected: on, Trace: off (file: none), Type: 82540EM, Reported speed: 0 Mbps, Boot priority: 0, Promisc Policy: deny, Bandwidth group: none   
    NIC 2:           disabled
    NIC 3:           disabled
    NIC 4:           disabled
    NIC 5:           disabled
    NIC 6:           disabled
    NIC 7:           disabled
    NIC 8:           disabled
    ...
```

... what I cannot figure out is what is dev-006's IP address.
I have looked at other questions and answers on unix.stackexchange.com
and I saw this one
([Can VirtualBox return IP address for launched VM?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88404/can-virtualbox-return-ip-address-for-launched-vm))
and it says I should be able to execute ...

```
    $ VBoxManage guestproperty get yourvmname "/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/V4/IP"
```

... but when I run ...

```
    $ VBoxManage guestproperty enumerate dev-006
```

... I get this output ...

```
    Name: /VirtualBox/HostInfo/VBoxVerExt, value: 4.3.10, timestamp: 1396471710759617000, flags: TRANSIENT, RDONLYGUEST
    Name: /VirtualBox/HostGuest/SysprepExec, value: , timestamp: 1396471710758813000, flags: TRANSIENT, RDONLYGUEST
    Name: /VirtualBox/HostGuest/SysprepArgs, value: , timestamp: 1396471710758950000, flags: TRANSIENT, RDONLYGUEST
    Name: /VirtualBox/HostInfo/VBoxRev, value: 93012, timestamp: 1396471710759735000, flags: TRANSIENT, RDONLYGUEST
    Name: /VirtualBox/HostInfo/VBoxVer, value: 4.3.10, timestamp: 1396471710759497000, flags: TRANSIENT, RDONLYGUEST
```

... so my question is why don't I see something like "/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/V4/IP"?

UPDATE:

Well I figured out why my VM doesn't have a IP address. 
I ran `VBoxManage controlvm dev-006 screenshotpng screen-shot-dev-006.png`.
See attached screen shot.[image]

If anyone can help me that I'd be very grateful. I guess I'll have to ask a new question about "this kernel requires an x86-64 cpu but only detected an i686 cpu virtualbox"

Thanks

Comment: It seems to me that your question title is wrong and misleading. You don't want to set it up but find out, don't you?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am not sure.  Maybe my VM does not have a IP so in that case I need to know how to give it one.  If my VM has an IP I need to figure out what it is.

Comment: In my tests, when the VM obtained an IP (I used dhcp for this, don't know how relevant that is), the 'guestproperty' command line you're using does seem to report the correct IP address. Perhaps the easiest way is just to check inside the VM and see if it actually has got an IP address?

Comment: Yes, but that is my problem. I have headless environment and I do not know how to access my VM without having an IP address to ssh to. Is there some other way I can "check inside the VM" ?

Comment: VirtualBox provides access to the display using RDP. You can enable this feature (it's disabled by default) using VBoxManage: http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html

Comment: I found out what's wrong ... but I am not able to figure what to do about it :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know, it is out date, but will be useful for anyone in the future.

I have the same problem. It looks like VirtualBox can't provide such information without GuestAdditions installed inside guest VM. So, after installing GuestAdditions inside your guest RHEL, you can run

```
VBoxManage list runningvms
VBoxManage guestproperty get "dev-006" "/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/V4/IP"
```